# How to Diagram Database Operations (not Structure)

Tags: database, uml, notation

I've been looking for a convenient way to diagram database **operations** (as opposed to database structure).  I'm familiar with Entity-Relationship diagrams for databases -- that's not what I'm looking for here.

Specifically, I'm working in SQL, and want a way to visualize complicated queries.  A flow chart could work, I suppose, or a UML activity diagram.  But I would expect there to be a commonly accepted notation for showing joins, unions, selects etc.  Searching has yielded nothing.  Any suggestions?

Here's sort of what I'd be expecting:
[image: simple SQL Statement diagram]

Which would suggest PostgreSQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  WITH 
      emp AS (
          SELECT * FROM employees
          WHERE now() is between hire and termination),
      sup AS (
          SELECT * FROM supervision
          WHERE now() is between role_start and role_end)

  SELECT emp2.name AS manager_name, sup.manager_id AS manager_id, emp.* 
  FROM emp
  JOIN sup on sup.employee_id = emp.id
  JOIN emp AS emp2 ON emp2.id = sup.manager_id
) AS team_list
```

[UPDATE:]

To clarify, I'm interested in a notation or graphical technique to help *develop* or visualize a complex query.  That is, for developing new queries more so than looking at existing queries.  It appears that "logical query plan" is what I'm looking for.

This is the closest thing I've found so far:

[image]

Comment: With DB operations you mean the way SQL works, not triggers, not NonSQL DBs? Database is a very broad area.

Comment: Yes, SQL.  For figuring out complicated queries.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: I'd guess that each SQL can be represented by a finite state machine which in the end delivers a number of rows. You could probably compile a SQL to result in those state machines. I wonder though if that would make it more clear :-/

Comment: You mean a Query Plan? I think these tend to be specific to a RDBMS implementation -- SQL Server e.g. has a Query Plan viewer.

Comment: That's pretty close, @muszeo.  I'll clarify my question, but primarily I'm looking for a visual tool/technique to develop complex queries as opposed to analyzing existing queries.